# Trouble loading 2 separate image sequences in the UIImageView

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I don't know if this is possible, but I need to load one image sequence in the imageView and have it play only once, then unload that sequence and load the second image sequence into the same imageView control.

Here is the code I'm using for loading and playing the first sequence.

```
imageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"openingSeq0001.jpg"], 
...etc.
[UIImage imageNamed:@"openingSeq0140.jpg"],nil];

imageView.animationDuration = 2;
imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1;
[imageView startAnimating];
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
[super viewDidLoad];
```

I now want to load and play the second sequence into the same imageView control once it has played through once. I have tried if statements, even a do while loop to make sure that the animation was at least played once and decremented the counter 1 and passed the value to the imageView.animationRepeatCount to equal 0.

```
imageView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
```

I thought I could figure it out, but I'm missing something somewhere. I can get the second grouping of images to run or the first and then is just stops. I used a do while loop for that.

I used this to make it work:

```
SEL methodSelector = @selector(startSeqTwo);
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.5 target:self selector:methodSelector userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

I used the selector after the first block of code to load the first sequence and called method:

```
-(void)startSeqTwo;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8112698/how-to-do-animations-using-images-efficiently-in-ios/17129053#answer-17129053

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SEL methodSelector = @selector(startSeqTwo);
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.5 target:self selector:methodSelector userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

This worked.

I used the selector after the first block of code to load the first sequence and called method: -(void)startSeqTwo;

Answer (score 0):

I have not done it but you could try using `self performSelectorOnMainThread:(SEL) withObject:(id) waitUntilDone:(BOOL)` function.

```
-(void)animateSequence{
   [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(animateFirstSequence) withObject:nil waitUnitilDone: YES];
   [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(animateSecondSequence) withObject:nil waitUnitilDone: YES];
}

-(void)animateFirstSequence{
  imageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"openingSeq0001.jpg"], 
...etc.
   [UIImage imageNamed:@"openingSeq0140.jpg"],nil];

  imageView.animationDuration = 2;
  imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1;
  [imageView startAnimating];
}

-(void)animateSecondSequence{
  imageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"openingSeq0001.jpg"], 
...etc.
   [UIImage imageNamed:@"openingSeq0140.jpg"],nil];

  imageView.animationDuration = 2;
  imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1;
  [imageView startAnimating];
}
```

**Edit**

You can also try checking if the UIImageView is stil animating and wait until finished to play another sequence. You would do it like this:

```
-(void)animateSequence{
  //First sequence
  imageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"openingSeq0001.jpg"], 
...etc.
   [UIImage imageNamed:@"openingSeq0140.jpg"],nil];

  imageView.animationDuration = 2;
  imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1;
  [imageView startAnimating];

  while([imageView isAnimating])
      //Do nothing

//second sequence
imageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"openingSeq0001.jpg"], 
...etc.
   [UIImage imageNamed:@"openingSeq0140.jpg"],nil];

  imageView.animationDuration = 2;
  imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1;
  [imageView startAnimating];
}
```

Comment: I tried to implement the code and in each case it did not work. The selector code gave me a warning and did not display anything. The while statement just left the display black, not loading anything. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: @Malin, the second code was working until iOS 4.0. I found that from that version isAnimating method is not returning NO when animation reaches end of the loop. Also found that you can use NSTimer to fire up the second animation.

Comment: Great! I will see if I can implement it. Thanks!

Comment: SEL methodSelector = @selector(startSeqTwo);
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.5 target:self selector:methodSelector userInfo:nil repeats:NO];  I used a separate method and a method selector to get it working. Thanks for all the help, I appreciate it!